# How to know and check a given string is a proper JSON or not?

Tags: android, android-json

As straightforward we can check a given string is a proper JSON format or not? as we can use

http://jsonlint.com/

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ etc etc.

but if the same task we wants to do programatically  how we can write a validator method in android as presently what I am trying to use is as follows.

Is this a proper way to achieve this, as I wrote the given function

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test) {

    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
        return true;
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        try {
            new JSONArray(test);
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

please suggest if there is something better. these all things **i need to check for test cases** as i know services will take care of correct json.

Comment: it is the work of the service to ensure that the correct json is returned.. or given to android, why spend un-necessary time doing that in android??!!

Comment: i am working on test cases..why downvote??

Comment: I dint do it.. i just asked.. as a comment ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
 try {
        Object obj = new JSONTokener(test).nextValue();

        if (obj instanceof JSONObject)
              //you have an object
        else if (obj instanceof JSONArray)
              //you have an array

    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this may help you,

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test)
{
    try {
        new JSONObject(test);
        return true;
} catch(JSONException ex) { 
    return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: what if string starts with an array

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check it following way,

```
public boolean isJSONValid(String test) 
{
    try 
    {
        new JSONObject(test);
        // If JsonObject is ok then check for JSONArray
        try 
        {
            new JSONArray(test);
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        try 
        {
            new JSONArray(test);
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException ex1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi kedarnathji namaste, are you sure this a better way?? as if new JSONObject(test); will be having an exception than it will go at  outer catch block , and it will create a problem if the given json is of array rather than object

Comment: See if there is an error at JsonObject then we shouldn't accept it. So directly return false.

Comment: yes i checked if it will be an array at json string than it is having a problem!! i am working on test cases